# Why are all my sessions being set to "null" by default after updating to 1.1.0.3?

Tags: session, meteor

It's weird. Instead of being `null` like the undefined kind of null, they're now being set to `"null"` like a string. It's completely preventing off all of my Session.default commands and screwing up wherever I have a condition like `if (Session.get('randomSession')) { // do something }`. Has this occurred for anyone else? Everything was working perfectly fine. But then I upgraded, and then instantly all of this happened.

Comment: Mine are doing the same. Must be a recent update issue?

Comment: I guess so. I feel a little better knowing that I'm not the only one.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm still having this issue.

Comment: I didn't feel like dealing with it so I decided to just do `sessionExists = function (session) {
    return !Session.equals(session, "null") && Session.get(session) !== null && Session.get(session) !== undefined
}    sessionGet = function (session) {
    if (sessionExists(session))
        return Session.get(session)
    else
        return null
}` A little hacky but it works. Then I just went through my files and did find and replace to change all the Session.get to sessionGet.